# Want to run js in loop

Tags: javascript

```js
var pause = document.querySelector(".pause1");
var audio = document.querySelector(".audio1");

function togglePlay() {
  if (audio.paused) {
    audio.play();
    pause.innerHTML = "ðŸ”Š";
  } else {
    audio.pause();
    pause.innerHTML = "ðŸ”‡";
    pause.style.color = " #a80000";
  }
}
```

```html
<li class="mp3-views">
  <div class="views-field mp3-play">
    <div class="pause1" onclick="togglePlay()">▶</div>
    <div class="player">
      <audio class="audio1" src="assets/images/audio.mp3" type="audio" loop=""></audio>
    </div>
  </div>
</li>
```

I want to run this code in loop because Play button is repeated in 'li' and I am not sure how to do it

Comment: Please elaborate on your question. It is not clear what the issue is

Comment: When you say "run in a loop" do you mean you want to have one event handler for many  li elements?

Comment: In simple words : I have multiple audios and structured in <ul><li>audio</li> <li>audio</li> </ul like this. Now when I am clicking the play button of 2nd li audio in that case first audio is playing.  so I need when click 2 or 3 or any number of audio that time only play same audio. 
I am not expert in english and as well as in Js so sorry for wording if anything wrong :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to place the event handler on the container and then used [closest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest) to get the parent li and the audio. This would allow you to add and remove as many audio clips as required and without having to add a click handler to each one.

```js
players.addEventListener("click", function(event) {

  let li = event.target.closest(".mp3-views");

  if (li) {
  
    let pause = li.querySelector(".pause1");
    let audio = li.querySelector(".audio1");


    if (audio.paused) {
      audio.play();
      pause.innerHTML = "ðŸ”Š";
    } else {
      audio.pause();
      pause.innerHTML = "ðŸ”‡";
      pause.style.color = " #a80000";
    }
  }

});
```

```html
<ul id="players">

  <li class="mp3-views">
    <div class="views-field mp3-play">
      <div class="pause1">▶</div>
      <div class="player">
        <audio class="audio1" src="https://www.soundhelix.com/examples/mp3/SoundHelix-Song-1.mp3" type="audio/mp3" loop=""></audio>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>

  <li class="mp3-views">
    <div class="views-field mp3-play">
      <div class="pause1">▶</div>
      <div class="player">
        <audio class="audio1" src="https://www.soundhelix.com/examples/mp3/SoundHelix-Song-2.mp3" type="audio" loop=""></audio>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>

  <li class="mp3-views">
    <div class="views-field mp3-play">
      <div class="pause1">▶</div>
      <div class="player">
        <audio class="audio1" src="https://www.soundhelix.com/examples/mp3/SoundHelix-Song-3.mp3" type="audio" loop=""></audio>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>

  </div>
```